# Time range using javascript or momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hi how to make Time range in 12-hour format using Javascript or MomentJS.

It need to be display from 12AM to 11:45PM. I need display every 15 min. Like this 12:00AM, 12:15AM, 12:30AM ect..

Here is image example how I need to display Time:

[image]

Comment: So.. you want to print all the times in a 12 hour period in 15 min intervals?

Comment: @Aron Yes but it need to have AM and PM

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using moment.js you can do this, which will give you exactly what you asked for:

```js
const start = moment().startOf('day');

const times = 24 * 4; // 24 hours * 15 mins in an hour

for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
  const toPrint = moment(start)
    .add(15 * i, 'minutes')
    .format('hh:mm A');

  console.log(toPrint);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: How to do this in 24-hours format? Couldn't figure this logic

Comment: @kiabbott replace the format string with `.format('HH:mm')`. You can see the full time format legend here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: any example without momentjs